# Error: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Trying to get my bot to log an edit message, this worked fine until I changed to a command handler.

```
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = async(oldMessage, newMessage) => { 

        if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) return;


        let editEmbed = new RichEmbed()
// Error occurs here:
        .setAuthor(`${oldMessage.author.tag}`, oldMessage.author.avatarURL)
        .setThumbnail(oldMessage.author.avatarURL)
        .setColor('RED')
        .setDescription(" **Message Edited**")
        .addField("Before Edit:", oldMessage.content, true)
        .addField("Edited Message:", newMessage.content, true)
        .addField("In Channel:", `<#${oldMessage.channel.id}>`, true)
        .setFooter("User ID: " + oldMessage.author.id)
        .setTimestamp()
        let sChannel = oldMessage.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "logs")
        sChannel.send(editEmbed);

}
```

I'm expecting the bot to log the edited message but when a message is edited I get the error:

```
(node:11761) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined
```

Comment: The error means that `oldMessage.author` is `undefined`.

Comment: how would I define both of them because i’m my old code I never had to define them.

Comment: Well I have no idea; you have to figure out what `oldMessage` actually looks like.